# text next to radio-button does not become center vertical

Tags: html, css

**restaurentInfo.html**

```
<div class="restaurent-container">
    <div class="restaurent-info">
        <label for "restaurent">Restaurent name </label>
        <select class="restaurent" name="restaurent-category">
    <option value="corporate">corporate</option>
    <option value="savings">Savings</option>
    <option value="personal">Personal</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    <div class="food-container">
        <input type="radio" name="radio" id="food" class="radio" />
        <label style="margin-left:10px;" for="food">Food</label>
        <input style="margin-left:10px;" type="radio" name="radio" id="food" class="radio" />
        <label style="margin-left:10px;" for="food">Drink</label>
    </div>

    <div style="margin-top:20px;" class="category-info">
        <label for "restaurent">Category </label>
        <select class="restaurent" name="restaurent-category">
    <option value="corporate">corporate</option>
    <option value="savings">Savings</option>
    <option value="personal">Personal</option>
    </select>
    </div>

    <div style="margin-top:20px;" class="item-info">
        <label for "restaurent">Category </label>
        <select class="restaurent" name="restaurent-category">
    <option value="corporate">corporate</option>
    <option value="savings">Savings</option>
    <option value="personal">Personal</option>
    </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

**restaurentInfo.scss**

```
.restaurent-container {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 30px 0 0 30px;
    .food-container {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try using line-height property in css

Comment: where should I put it ?

Comment: on label tag for alignment

Comment: ok,thanks , it worked